# I want to get data from another site and display it on my site with my old CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made this site using HTML CSS
And I want to get data from this site **[I want to get data from this site](http://103.152.199.179/YCCE/Suported%20file/Supprted%20file/SERIES%20WISE%20BOOKS/CIVIL%20ENGINEERING/)**
and update now in my site there are 6 files so I wrote CSS according to them
But in the future, it will be more. So how can I get the files from that site, and it should auto-update on my site. Whatever new files will come, the CSS that I have written for the old 6 files should also apply to it.
So can anyone help me?

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

}

body {
    /* font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; */
    overflow-x: hidden;
    /* overflow: hidden;
    Hide scrollbars  */
}


.nav {
    background-color: rgb(90, 183, 241);
    padding: 7px;
    margin-top: -1px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}



/* ADMINISTRATION Start */
.nav ul {
    display: inline-flex;
    list-style: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: -4px 0px -5px 0px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    font-weight: bolder;
}

.nav ul li {
    margin: 1px 1px 1px 1px;

}


.nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding-inline: 5px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
}

/* LOGO */
.logo img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 25px;
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px 10px 5px 0px;
}


.nav .fa {
    margin-left: 1px;
}

.sub-menu-1 .fa-caret-right {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.active,
.nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: #bca3f2;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: black;
    padding: 4px 2px 4px;
}

/* SUB-MENU-1 */
.sub-menu-1 ul li a {
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;

}

.sub-menu-1 ul li:hover {
    background-color: #bca3f2;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;

}

.sub-menu-1 ul li a:hover {
    color: black;
}

.sub-menu-1 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    top: 30px;
    margin-left: -3;
}

.sub-menu-1 a {
    padding: 5% 0px 1px 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.nav ul li:hover .sub-menu-1 {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgb(72, 162, 197);
}

.nav ul li:hover .sub-menu-1 ul {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px;
}


/* inside sub menu User Management */
.fa-caret-right {
    float: right;
    right: 2px;
}

/*sub-in-menu1 start  */

.sub-in-menu1 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);
    margin-top: -29px;
    margin-left: 250px;
    z-index: 1;
    justify-content: space-between;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}

.hover-me .sub-in-menu1 a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px 100px 5px 1px;
}

.hover-me .sub-in-menu1 ul li {
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}


.hover-me:hover .sub-in-menu1 {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgb(72, 162, 197);
}

/* sub-in-menu1 End */
/* ADMINISTRATION End */

/* ACADEMIC Start */
/* sub-in-menu2 Start */
.sub-in-menu2 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);
    margin-top: -29px;
    margin-left: 220px;
    z-index: 1;
    justify-content: space-between;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}

.hover-me .sub-in-menu2 a {
    margin: 0px 60px 5px 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

.hover-me .sub-in-menu2 ul li {
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}


.hover-me:hover .sub-in-menu2 {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgb(72, 162, 197);
}

/* sub-in-menu2 End */
/* ACADEMIC End */

/* Responsive */
@media screen and (max-width:700px) {
    .nav ul {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: left;
        /* If you want the text to be left-aligned on small screens */
    }
}


/* FOOTER */
/* FOOTER */

strong {
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.main-footer {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #444;
    border-top: 1px solid #d2d6de;
}

.navbar-fixed-bottom {
    bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-width: 1px 0 0;
}


.navbar-fixed-bottom,
.navbar-fixed-top {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1030;
    text-align: center;
}

.content-wrapper {
    min-height: 565px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>YC_LIBRARY</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,600;0,700;1,800&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/fontawesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/892d11d632.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="nav">
            <ul>
                <div class="logo">
                    <img src="YCC Logo.png" alt="YCC Logo">
                </div>
                <li class="active"><a href="#">BOOKS<i class="fa
                                fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                    <div class="sub-menu-1">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="hover-me"><a href="#">UG COURSES<i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></a>
                                <div class="sub-in-menu1">
                                    <ul>

                                        <li><a href="http://103.152.199.179/YCCE/Suported%20file/Supprted%20file/SERIES%20WISE%20BOOKS/CIVIL%20ENGINEERING/"
                                                target="_blank">Civil
                                                Engineering</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Mechanical
                                                Engineering</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Electrical
                                                Engineering</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Electronics &
                                                Telecommunication</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Engineering</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Electronics
                                                Engineering</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Computer Technology</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Information
                                                Technology</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Computer Science &
                                                Engineering</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Computer Science &
                                                Engineering(Artificial
                                                Intelligence
                                                & Machine
                                                Learning)</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Computer Science &
                                                Design</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Industrial IOT</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Artificial
                                                Intelligence
                                                & Data Science</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="hover-me"><a href="#">PG COURSES<i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></a>
                                <div class="sub-in-menu1">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#">Structural
                                                Engineering</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">CAD/CAM</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Integrated Power
                                                System</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Computer Science &
                                                Engineering</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Communication
                                                Engineering</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Environmental
                                                Engineering</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>

                            </li>
                            <li class="hover-me"><a href="#">OTHER BOOKS<i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></a>
                                <div class="sub-in-menu1">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#">Engineering &
                                                Technology</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">General books</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">PD books</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="hover-me"><a href="#">APPLIED
                                    SCIENCES
                                    &HUMANITIES<i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></a>
                                <div class="sub-in-menu1">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#">Physics</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Chemistry</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Mathematics</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Communication Skill</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Social Science</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Sciences</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">JOURNALS <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                    <div class="sub-menu-1">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="hover-me"><a href="#">IEEE ASPP
                                    ONLINE
                                    JOURNALS<i class="fa
                                            fa-caret-right"></i>
                                </a>
                                <div class="sub-in-menu2">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#">Download List</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="hover-me"><a href="#">CONFERENCE
                                    PROCEEDINGS<i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></a>
                                <div class="sub-in-menu2">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#">Download List</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>

                            </li>
                            <li class="hover-me"><a href="#">PRINT JOURNALS<i class="fa
                                            fa-caret-right"></i></a>
                                <div class="sub-in-menu2">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Download List</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="hover-me"><a href="#">MAT JOURNALS<i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></a>
                                <div class="sub-in-menu2">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#">DOWNLOAD ONLINE
                                                JOURNALS
                                                NATIONAL LIST</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">ONLINE USERNAME
                                                PASSWORD</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">ONLINE PORTAL</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="hover-me"><a href="#">OPAC<i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></a>
                                <div class="sub-in-menu2">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#">OPAC PORTAL</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">E-RESOURCES <i class="fa
                                fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                    <div class="sub-in-menu1">
                        <ul>
                            <li>

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <footer class="main-footer navbar-fixed-bottom text-center">
                    <strong>
                        Designed and Developed By: MIS/ERP
                    </strong>
                </footer>
        </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I think your question might be misleading. It appears you are uploading PDF files to a site with an IP address ending in `.179`, and you are looking for a solution that when a *new* PDF is uploaded to that site, your HTML site gets updated to reflect that new file has been added. Is this correct? If so, this is not a CSS question, but rather a Javascript or PHP question.

Comment: Oh thank you so you mean that I want to make html and php to that